# What is the range of $\frac{\left( \sum_i x_i y_i \right)^2}{\sum_i x_i^2 \sum_i y_i^2}$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products

What is the range of $\frac{\left( \sum_i x_i y_i \right)^2}{\sum_i x_i^2 \sum_i y_i^2}$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$? i.e., is it bounded above and below by some finite number?

I know that
\begin{align}
    \sum x_i^2 = ||x||^2 \\
    \sum y_i^2 = ||y||^2 \\
    \left(\sum_i(x_iy_i) \right)^2 = \langle x, y\rangle^2
\end{align}

The numerator and denominator are both positive, so the lower bound must be at least $0$. Is there a relationship between the numerator and denominator that would help me find the bounds?

Comment: By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $$|\langle x,y\rangle|^2\leqslant\|x\|^2\|y\|^2\rightarrow\frac{|\langle x,y\rangle|^2}{\|x\|^2\|y\|^2}\leqslant1$$ so that range is contained in $[0,1]$. To prove that the upper-bound is $1$ take $x=y$

Comment: @Alessandro Ah. Also, what is the point of the absolute value on the dot product, when it's going to be squared? Is there any significance to it?

Comment: No, just force of habit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula on the scalar product $$\langle x,y \rangle = |x| \cdot |y| \cos \alpha$$

You hence get that the range is $(0,1)$. Note that this is a bit circular because that is exactly how the angle between two vectors in higher dimensional space is defined (although you can embed them in a plane and get an angle like that).

Another possibility is the Cauchy-Schwatz inequality and you get an upper bound of $1$. The lower bound of $0$ is clear.